# How to fetch dynamic value from xml file upload in jmeter

Tags: xml, csv, file-upload, dynamic, jmeter

I am uploading the file [test.xml] as a POST HTTPS Request in 'File Upload' as a File Path.
And defined other values are defined as a Paramater.
In [test.xml] file **xml values are defined as ${InstanceId}**
${InstanceId} values are fetched from the CSV data file

**Error:**
From the CSV file,  ${InstanceId} values are not fetching from the each records and passing to the ${InstanceId} values in the xml file

From CSV file, Instance Id value should pass to the Xml file.

Can you help to solve the Error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N42o.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO3Xs.png)

Thanks,
Thenmozhi C

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, you can try doing something like:

1. Replace `${InstanceId}` in your `test.xml` file with something like `###CHANGEME###`
2. Replace the filename in the Files Upload tab of the HTTP Request sampler with

   ```
   test${__threadNum}.xml
   ```

   [image]
3. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of this request and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new File('test' + (ctx.getThreadNum() + 1) + '.xml').text = new File('test.xml').text.replace('###CHANGEME###', vars.get('InstanceId'))
   ```

The code will:

1. Create a new XML file for each virtual user, i.e. `test1.xml` for 1st thread, `test2.xml` for 2nd thread, etc.
2. Substitute `###CHANGEME###` in the original `test.xml` file with the current value of `InstanceId` JMeter Variable

Check [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) to learn what do these `ctx` and `vars` guys mean if interested.